# hashchange with attr('id') but load content from attr('href') using jquery

Tags: jquery, hash

hey guys, I'm not sure if it can be done or not but i'm just curious.

this is my code and I was wondering if it could work theoretically...

```
//------------------------------------------------------------------
// Menu links
//------------------------------------------------------------------
var newHash      = "",
uri = "",
$content = $("#main-content"),
content  = '#main-content',
$wrap    = $("#wrap"),
baseHeight   = 0,
$el;

$wrap.height($wrap.height());
baseHeight = $wrap.height() - $content.height();

$("nav a").live('click', function(){
    window.location.hash = $(this).attr("id");
    url = $(this).attr("href");
    uri = windows.location.hash;
    return false;
});
/*$("nav").delegate("a", "click", function() {
    window.location.hash = $(this).attr("href");
    console.log(window.location.hash);
    return false;
});*/

$(window).bind('hashchange', function(){
    //window.location.hash = $(this).attr("href");
    //newHash = window.location.hash.substring(1);
    u = uri.substring(1);
    console.log(u);
    if (window.location.hash = u) {
        $wrap.find("#main-content").fadeOut(200, function() {
            $wrap.load(u + " #main-content", function() {
                $content.fadeIn(function() {
                    $wrap.animate({
                        height: baseHeight + $content.height() + "px"
                    }, 500);
                });
            });
        });
    }
});
$(window).trigger('hashchange');
```

Current behaviors:
-- when I load www.abc.com/ the URI turns into www.abc.com/# automatically
-- when I click on a menu link it turns the URI to www.abc.com/#!/files/2
(where **2** is the ID of the user and   **!/files/2** is the id of the link)
-- when the click is invoke it quickly then turn the URI to www.abc.com/file.php#
which will now just load the file directly from the server without the ajax effect of loading in content from the page rather than going to a direct link.

I have at one point successfully gotten the link to show as:

http://www.abc.com/#!/file/2 and load content from file.php but with that success I wasn't able to trick the browser into seeing the URI for what it is and load content from file.php based off the URI on a page refresh (for bookmarking reasons)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know triggers a change of the URL in the browser (except the hashchanges) a load of a new page (in this case a reload). Therefore it should not be possible to show "file.php" in the status bar when #!/file/2 is called...